# `hugo gen doc` produces no documentation

Tags: hugo

The [Hugo documentation](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_gen_doc/) says the command `hugo gen doc` should generate up-to-date Markdown documentation for the Hugo command-line interface (CLI). My problem is that when I use the command no documentation is generated.

When I use command `hugo gen doc` no documentation is produced.

The hugo version is 0.115.4

The operating system (OS) is Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

The output from the `hugo gen doc` command says:

> Generating Hugo command-line documention in /tmp/hugodoc/ ...
>
> Done.

However, after the command is run, folder /tmp/hugodoc/ does not exist. i.e. It has not been created by the command.

Next, I created the /tmp/hugodoc/ folder before running the `hugo gen doc` command but still no documentation is created in /tmp/hugodoc/ even though the output from the command still said that it had generated documentation and no errors were shown.

> Generating Hugo command-line documention in /tmp/hugodoc/ ...
>
> Done.

The command `hugo gen doc --dir hugo-gen-doc` successfully generates Markdown documentation in folder hugo-gen-doc/

Why does command `hugo gen doc` not generate documentation in /tmp/hugodoc/ as per the [Hugo documentation](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_gen_doc/)?